# Print 3 JAVA program's output in the separate consecutive lines, sharing same console, using \r in a multiprocessing scenario

Tags: java, multiprocessing, apache-flink, carriage-return

I have 3 `java` programs having individual `main functions` which are called by a parent program on 3 separate threads. All three programs prints value of a counter in a single console using below code

For program # 1

```java
   System.out.print(ANSI_PURPLE + "  \r  EEG Sensor count =" + Sensor1_tuple_count);
   System.out.flush();
```

For program # 2

```java
    System.out.print(ANSI_PURPLE + " \r  BP Sensor count = " + Sensor2_tuple_count + " ");
    System.out.flush();
```

For program # 3

```java
    System.out.print(ANSI_PURPLE + "\r  ECG Sensor count =" + Sensor3_tuple_count);
    System.out.flush();
```

all of these are updated inside a lambda function, right now all these values are overwriting one another, How do I get output like this

```java
EEG Sensor count = X
BP Sensor count  = Y
ECG Sensor count = Z
```

---

### EDIT 1

Code for a single program using Flink is given below

```java
  public class bp_sensor {

    public static final String ANSI_RED     = "\u001B[31m";
    public static final String ANSI_BLUE    = "\u001B[34m";
    public static final String ANSI_PURPLE  = "\u001B[35m";


    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {

        Constants constants = null;

        //setting the envrionment variable as StreamExecutionEnvironment
        StreamExecutionEnvironment envrionment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        envrionment.setParallelism(1);


        DataStream<Sensor_Event> bp_stream  = envrionment
                .addSource(new EventGenerator_bp_sensor(constants.bp_data_rate,constants.bp_run_time_sec,1,1))
                .name("BP stream")
                .setParallelism(1);



        if(constants.send_to_timekeeper){

            //Sending the stream to timekeeper
            bp_stream.map(new RichMapFunction<Sensor_Event, String>() {
                @Override
                public String map(Sensor_Event event) throws Exception {
                    String tuple = event.toString();
                    System.out.println(tuple);
                    return tuple + "\n";
                }
            }).writeToSocket(constants.timekeeper_ip, 8003, new SimpleStringSchema() );

        }




        // Sending the stream to mobile phone

        if(constants.send_to_android){

            DataStreamSink<String> total_tuples = bp_stream.map(new RichMapFunction<Sensor_Event, String>() {

                IntCounter Sensor2_tuple_count;

                @Override
                public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
                    super.open(parameters);
                    this.Sensor2_tuple_count = getRuntimeContext().getIntCounter("total_tuples");
                }

                @Override
                public String map(Sensor_Event event) throws Exception {
                    String tuple = event.toString();
                    Sensor2_tuple_count.add(1);

                    System.lineSeparator();
                    System.out.print(ANSI_PURPLE + " \r  BP Sensor count = " + Sensor2_tuple_count + " ");
                    System.out.flush();

//                    System.out.println(ANSI_BLUE + tuple);

                    return tuple + "\n";
                }
            }).writeToSocket(constants.mobile_ip, 7003, new SimpleStringSchema() );


        }



        //start the execution
        JobExecutionResult executionResult = envrionment.execute();

        Integer number_of_tuples = (Integer) executionResult.getAllAccumulatorResults().get("total_tuples");
        int input_rate = number_of_tuples/constants.bp_run_time_sec;

        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(ANSI_BLUE   + "  Expected Input rate of BP Sensor     = " + constants.bp_data_rate + " tuples/second");
        System.out.println(ANSI_RED    + "  Actual Input rate of BP Sensor       = " + input_rate + " tuples/second");
        System.out.println(ANSI_PURPLE + "  Total # of tuples sent by BP Sensor  = " + number_of_tuples );



    }// main



} //class
```

Code of parent program is

```java
public class start_sensors {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ecg_sensor ecg_sensor = null;
        bp_sensor bp_sensor = null;
        eeg_sensor eeg_sensor = null;


        Thread thread1 = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    ecg_sensor.main(null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };


        Thread thread2 = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    bp_sensor.main(null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };


        Thread thread3 = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    eeg_sensor.main(null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };


        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();


    } //main
} //class
```

Comment: How do you mean, "all of these are updated inside a lambda function"? How are they "overwriting each other"? Please provide your code.

Comment: Please see updated question

Answer (score 0):

As for threads, to control the order in which they work you must use some kind of synchronization. As to the behavior of the console, it out of scope of Java and depends on the environment.